# Apache directory listing restriction per IP bases

Tags: apache, .htaccess, indexing, directory

i need to limit the directory listing for all users except certain IP's. Any idea how to do that?

the option for it should be:

```
Options -Indexes
```

and let's say the directory i need to restrict is /restricted/

```
<Directory /restricted>
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

but how to place the IP restriction for all but, for instance, 127.0.0.1

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
Options -Indexes
<Files *>
deny from all
allow from 213.106.26.195
allow from 213.106.15.132
Options +Indexes
</Files>
```

I used  directive because I tried it in .htaccess, but in your server profile you can use the  directive as well, of course.

Comment: I just tried this but it only partially works.  It restricts directory listing but also restricts EVERYTHING.  IF your IP does not match you can't view a file either

Comment: Well then I guess that's not so easy - almost impossible. I haven't found solution for restricting *only* the directory listing.